# child collection is not updating in hibernate with cascade all?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have two tables - Student and Address. They have one to many relationship. Student entity is having collection of address entity. When i updating collection of address in student. Its not updating the data and giving this error. When i was updating the parent entity with child collection, its taking next to be incremented key which is not in the database.  -

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3079)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3521)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at com.HibernateExample.test.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:51)


Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "address" violates foreign key constraint "student_fk"
  Detail: Key (id)=(5) is not present in table "student".
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2476)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2189)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:300)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:169)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:186)
    ... 14 more
```

Student.java

```
public class Student {

    public int id;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public int age;
    public Set<Address> address = new HashSet<>(0);

    public Set<Address> getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(Set<Address> address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

Address.java

```
public class Address {

    public int id;
    public String streetName;
    public String cityName;
    public String stateName;
    public String plotNo;
    public Student student;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getStreetName() {
        return streetName;
    }
    public void setStreetName(String streetName) {
        this.streetName = streetName;
    }
    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }
    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }
    public String getStateName() {
        return stateName;
    }
    public void setStateName(String stateName) {
        this.stateName = stateName;
    }
    public String getPlotNo() {
        return plotNo;
    }
    public void setPlotNo(String plotNo) {
        this.plotNo = plotNo;
    }
    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }
    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

}
```

HibernateTest.java

```
public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate-cfg.xml");
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

        Session session =   sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT);

        System.out.println(session.getFlushMode().name());

        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        Student  student =  (Student) session.get(Student.class, 3);


        Address address = new Address();
        address.setStateName("Kerala");
        address.setCityName("Old Delhi");
        address.setStreetName("Uttaam Nagar");
        address.setPlotNo("158A");

        address.setStudent(student);
        student.getAddress().add(address);
        session.update(student);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();

        sessionFactory.close();

    }   
}
```

address.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="com.HibernateExample.entity.Address" table="address">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the address detail. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="increment" />
      </id>
      <property name="streetName" column="street_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="cityName" column="city_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="stateName" column="state_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="plotNo" column="plot_no" type="string"/>

      <many-to-one name="student" class="com.HibernateExample.entity.Student" >
            <column name="student_id" not-null="true"></column>
      </many-to-one> 

   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

student.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="com.HibernateExample.entity.Student" table="student">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the student detail. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="increment" />
      </id>
      <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="string"  length="40" />
      <property name="lastName" column="last_name" type="string" length="40" />
      <property name="age" column="age" type="int"/>

      <set name="address" cascade="all">
         <key column="student_id"/>
         <one-to-many class="com.HibernateExample.entity.Address"/>
      </set>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Try overriding equals and hashcode in your entities.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Copied your files + configured hibernate.cfg. Worked as expected. Maybe you can share the complete sample code for reproduce?

Comment: This should be in the mapping files though at the top otherwise how does it recognize hibernate-mapping tag <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

Comment: @J-Alex....how can i share with you ??

Comment: @AnkitGoel...It is there....i just didnt add that here....without them how will my code can work

Answer (score 2):

From the [Session javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html), `Session.update()` is specified to work with a *detached* entity instance. "If there is a persistent instance with the same identifier, an exception is thrown." Exactly which exception is not specified, and cascading might send it down a complex code path, which could result in this error.

The `Student` object you modify is not *detached*, but rather *persistent*, because you got it by loading from the `Session` and have not closed the `Session` or done anything else that would detach it. This means that all modifications to it are saved to the database automatically, with no need for any manual call on `Session`. This is specified in the class javadoc for `Session`, with the sentence "Changes to persistent instances are detected at flush time and also result in an SQL UPDATE."

Simply delete the line `session.update(student);`, and I think your code will start working, including saving the new address through the cascaded relationship when you commit the transaction.

It's been a while since I've worked with cascades so I'm not entirely certain, but you might also need to set cascade on the other side of the relationship.

Comment: @AmitDas Both removing the update call and adding cascade=all to the address mapping file? If both of those together don't solve it, I think I'd need to experiment a bit to find the problem. If you post a complete sample project (on github, or an archive file or something) so I can be sure my setup matches yours, I'll take a look tonight.

Comment: save is working fine with parent entity and child collection but only update is creating problem. If you see, the error is saying that it is taking student_id as 5 which is not in the database, only student_id with 4 is in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The "student_id" is not associated with any of your primary keys. If "student_id" exists in both Student and Address tables then change this line in your student mapping file from "id" to "student_id":

```
<id name="id" type="int" column="student_id">
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check your database table with a database table viewer/browser.
It seems you try to insert an ID that already exists in the database (5)

Comment: no it doesnt exits....i have checked.....what is happening that when i am updating any child entity from its parent, then its parent is taking next increment id